# First automated authentication test using Selenium Webdriver in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium, authentication, webdriver, testcase

I'm running a my first automated test using selenium webdriver in eclipse on a demo static site.  The main purpose of the test is to show that a transaction is confirmed in my log file, e.g. should say something like "confirmation received"/ or not?  This should come after the following step:

"//Find to Confirm Button and click on it
        driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
        logger.info("Click Confirmar Button");"

However, I'm not quite sure  what code to use to get this result.  A confirmation message pops up after this button in clicked. I want to verify that the transaction worked somehow, and if it wasn't received I also want a notification saying so.

Can anyone help with this??

Complete code below:

```
package com.scotia.test;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.Optional;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;



public class ScotiaTest1 {


@Test
@Parameters("test1")
public void beforeTest(@Optional("optional") String type)
{
    System.out.println("Type in Before Test is="+type);
}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/theone/Downloads/chromedriver-new");

        Logger logger=Logger.getLogger("Test1");

        DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");

        // Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        logger.info("Chrome opened");


        //Login using Username and Password
        driver.get("https://username:password@apps.url.com/_Prototype/desktop/html/Chile_index.html#"); 
        logger.info("Application Launched");

        //Wait for 1 Sec
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        logger.info("Pause Execution for 1 second");

        //Find Proximity Serie A link and click on it
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#investing_tab tr:nth-child(7) a.acct-name")).click();
        logger.info("Click Proximidad Serie A");

        //Wait for 1 Sec
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        logger.info("Pause Execution for 1 second");    

        //Find New Funds Button and click on it
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".pad-top-10.txt-right .btn.action-btn")).click();
        logger.info("Click Button Nuevo Fondo");

        //Wait for 1 Sec
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        logger.info("Pause Execution for 1 second");

        //Select Field Rescue investment and choose Rescue
        Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("mf_action")));
        dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Inversión");
        logger.info("Select Inversión from dropdown");

        //Wait for 1 Sec
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        logger.info("Pause Execution for 1 second");

        //Select Field Current account and choose current account
        dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("selaccount_drpdown")));
        dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Cuenta Corriente *** 0002 USD 10.000,00");
        logger.info("Select Cuenta Corriente *** 0002 USD 10.000,00 from dropdown");
        //Wait for 1 Sec

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        logger.info("Pause Execution for 1 second");

        //Select Field Fund Type and choose medium term
        dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("term")));
        dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Deuda de Mediano y Largo Plazo");
        logger.info("Select Deuda de Mediano y Largo Plazo from dropdown");

        //Wait for 1 Sec
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        logger.info("Pause Execution for 1 second");

        //Select Field Mutual Fund Name and choose Proximity Series A
        dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("typefund")));
        dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Proximidad Serie A");
        logger.info("Select Proximidad Serie A from dropdown");

        //Wait for 1 Sec
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        logger.info("Pause Execution for 1 second");

        //Select Field Fund account Name and choose 001
        dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("sub_accnt")));
        dropdown.selectByVisibleText("001");
        logger.info("Select 001 from dropdown");

        //Wait for 1 Sec
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        logger.info("Pause Execution for 1 second");

        //Select Field Rode and type 222
        driver.findElement(By.id("amount_field")).sendKeys("222");
        logger.info("Type 222 in Monto text feild");

        //Wait for 1 Sec
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        logger.info("Pause Execution for 1 second");

        //Find to Accept Button and click on it
        driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
        logger.info("Click Aceptar button");

        //Wait for 1 Sec
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        logger.info("Pause Execution for 1 second");

        //Find to Confirm Button and click on it
        driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
        logger.info("Click Confirmar Button");

        //Wait for 1 Sec
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        logger.info("Pause Execution for 1 second");

        //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("RUIFW-alert-success.getText()"));(does not do anything)


     // Close browser

        driver.quit();
        logger.info("Close Browser");

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to verify that the confirmation appears, you should assert that the confirmation exists and that its content matches what is expected.

The steps should be:

1. Assert the confirmation exists and is visible
2. Verify that all text matches the text you expect to see
3. Verify that any expected links are visible and lead to the appropriate page

Also, please consider the following:

- It looks like you should not have '.getText()' included in your cssSelector.
- It is considered bad practice to have tests riddled with
  Thread.sleep(). You should have a look here
  http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp for an
  alternative.
- When you post code on a public site, you should make sure to scrub it
  of sensitive information such as login credentials.